# Can I use Inline CSS one time only

Tags: css

I have heard that using inline CSS in your websites is bad.

Here's an example.

Let's say i do have a class mycss

```
.mycss { margin: 10px 0 11px 12px; text-align: left; color: red; }
```

And i will be using it in one of my divs

```
<div class="mycss">DIV ONE</div>
```

i want to use the same styles in my DIV TWO , this the margin will be set to 0.

```
<div class="mycss" style="margin: 0;">DIV TWO</div>
```

Is this a Bad Practice?

**EDIT** Another Example to make it more clearer.

I got 5 DIVS

```
 <div class="mycss">ONE</div>
 <div class="mycss">TWO</div>
 <div class="mycss">THREE</div>
 <div class="mycss">FOUR</div>
 <div class="mycss">FIVE</div>
```

Let's say i do have a class mycss

```
.mycss { margin: 10px 0 11px 12px; text-align: left; color: red; }
```

Now i want all 5 DIVS to have different margins. Should i go create 5 more classes in each of them? or just do an Inline CSS?

Will it be:

A.

```
 .marginfordivone { margin: 1px 2px 3px 4px }
 .marginfordivtwo { margin: 2px 4px 6px 6px }
 .marginfordivthree { margin: 8px 5px 1px 3px }
 .marginfordivfour { margin: 1px 2px 2px 2px }
 .marginfordivfive { margin: 1px 4px 8px 4px }.


 <div class="mycss marginfordivone">ONE</div>
 <div class="mycss marginfordivtwo">TWO</div>
 <div class="mycss marginfordivthree">THREE</div>
 <div class="mycss marginfordivfour">FOUR</div>
 <div class="mycss marginfordivfive">FIVE</div>
```

B.

```
 <div class="mycss" style="margin: 1px 2px 3px 4px">ONE</div>
 <div class="mycss" style="margin: 2px 4px 6px 6px">TWO</div>
 <div class="mycss" style="margin:  8px 5px 1px 3px">THREE</div>
 <div class="mycss" style="margin: 1px 2px 2px 2px">FOUR</div>
 <div class="mycss" style="margin: 1px 4px 8px 4px">FIVE</div>
```

A or B

Comment: If you don't need the values to change in the future then it's fine

Comment: will DIV TWO occur anywhere else on the site? if not then I'd say no it's not that bad of a practice and you should go for it, if you use it through out the site on the other hand then yes don't do it

Comment: perhaps you could use nth-child to get the div?

Comment: now im confused! other's says it bad, and others says its fine. I'm only going to use it in a single div only. Just one time only. Ofcourse, if i will be using it in a different DIVS then i would set a class for it.

Comment: @JeremiLiwanag It's your decision. You can use inline styles, just here and there, but then I hope I won't inherit any of your projects ;). I learned the hard way why I should not use them.

Comment: @Breezer How can you be sure that div will never occur anywhere else on the site one month later? Isn't it easier to write future-proof code?

Comment: Okies, Thanks guys! I'll follow the comment with most upvotes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bad practice.

Why don't you simply create two different classes?

```
.mycss { text-align: left; color: red; }
.mycss2 { margin: 10px 0 11px 12px; }

<div class="mycss mycss2">DIV ONE</div>
<div class="mycss">DIV TWO</div>
```

### Update (to fit updated question)

You still shouldn't use inline css to override css classes. Just add another class (like i showed). If you have 5 different margins, you need to ask yourself why you are doing it. In general, you should be able to use margin-left, margin-right, margin-top and margin-bottom separately and then create css classes that are defined by their intention and not by their implementation. For instance:

```
.narrowSideMargins { 
    margin-left: 2px; 
    margin-right: 2px; 
}
.wideSideMargins { 
    margin-left: 10px; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
}
```

You may obviously choose any composition of the margins, but it's important to remember to define the classes by their intention and NOT by their actual current properties. This will answer both your original (and current) question and [bazmegakapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468793/bazmegakapa)'s comment (methodologically).

Comment: that's just an example. anyway, i edited my question.. replaced scenario into example...  What if i want a my five DIVS to have different margins.. with the same text align and color? should i set a class for those different margins???

Comment: @JeremiLiwanag Yes. Or you can use some other CSS selectors. But if you add classes, they should not be like `margin10` and `margin20`. If you later want to change 20 to 30, you've hit another maintainability problem :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will be a bad practice. Because, when u have most of the CSS styles in common and just want to change one or two style properties, you can do the following:

1) Create a Class for the most common style properties.
2) Create different classes for each of the individual changes.

```
  .mycss { text-align: left; color: red;}
    .mycss2 {margin: 10px 0 11px 12px; }
.mycss3 {margin: 0px}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is.**

Inline styles make your project very hard to maintain. Just add a different class on your second div, or use one of the many other [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) to match it.

There are edge cases of course, where inline styles might come handy. Generating HTML server-side and having to put a generated CSS style on your element comes into mind, for example setting a `background-image` on it for which the image URL comes from the database.

Other than these, you are better off without *ever thinking* about using inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can write different two class as:

CSS:

`.mycss-1 { margin: 10px 0 11px 12px; text-align: left; color: red; }`

HTML:

`<div class="mycss">DIV ONE</div>`

CSS:

`.mycss-2 { margin: 0; text-align: left; color: red; }`

HTML:

`<div class="mycss-2">DIV TWO</div>`

Just make it more optimize as:

CSS:

```
.mycss{ text-align: left; color: red; }
.margin-1{ margin: 10px 0 11px 12px; }
.margin-2{ margin: 0; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mycss margin-1">DIV ONE</div>
<div class="mycss margin-2">DIV TWO</div>
```